# Check if a value is the next or previous day in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to count how many times the next or previous day of a day has a certain value when that day has a certain value.
(I simplify the database structures to make you understand better what I need)
Example:

```
Date          Event
2015-01-01       x
2015-01-02       x
2015-01-03      rest
2015-01-04      sick
2015-01-05       x
2015-01-06      sick
2015-01-07      rest
2015-01-08       x
2015-01-09       x
```

I need to count how many days a person is sick after or before the rest day.
In this case the result from the query should be: 2

Comment: Is the answer 2 because there are 2 rest days, both of which have qualifying sick days? Or is it 2 because, for the period of time in your sample, there are 2 qualifying sick days? Be careful how you structure your test data to validate your logic.

Comment: @SMor the answer is 2 because there are 2 sick days after or before the rest day, I need to know if the sick day is before or after the rest day to find out the people who want to take two days off instead of one pretending to be sick and count how many times they do this

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cumulative sum of `'rest'` to get groups.  Then aggregate and filter:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when event = 'rest' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by date) as rest_grp
      from t
     ) t
where state = 'sick' 
group by rest_grp;
```

This actually returns three rows -- because there are three gruops (before the rest, in-between, and after the last).

If you specifically want the middle group, then use:

```
where state = 'sick' and rest_grp = 1
```